# Javascript: Need to proceed to another page

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using Javascript for deleting a record. But my problem is, when I click the **image button** its not redirecting to the page I want instead it will remain on the page...

Here's my code:

```
echo "<button type='submit' name='deletePlaylist[]' value='" . $row['id']."' onClick='myFunction()' style='border: 0; background: transparent; cursor: pointer;'><img src='image/delete.png' /></button> ";
```

I'm using the **button** because I'm using an image if I used the **input** its not working... So I decided to use **button**

Here's my code in my javascript:

```
function myFunction()
{
var Xcancel;
var Rokay=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
if (Rokay==true)
  {
    window.location = 'delete.php'; 

  }
else
  {
  Xcancel="You pressed Cancel!";
  }

}
</script>
```

I already tried the  `window.navigate("delete.php");` or the `window.location.href='delete.php'`  also not working...

The confirmation message is displaying already but my main problem its not going to the **delete.php** where in that form is my deleting function...

NOTE:

The button is under of the `<form name='form' method='post' action="">`, the `delete.php` is in the same folder... Before there is no *confirmation message* and its going to the delete.php but now I tried to insert a confirmation message then its not going to the delete.php... The form action is empty because I have a click able dropdown list where it will proceed to the result.php

Here's the code for my dropdown list:

```
<select id="year"name="year"onChange="this.form.action='booking_delete_two.php'; this.form.submit()">
<option value="2013" <?php if($get_year=='2013') echo "selected"?>>2013</option>
<option value="2014" <?php if($get_year=='2014') echo "selected"?>>2014</option>
</select>




<select name="id" onChange="this.form.action='booking_delete_three.php'this.form.submit()">
<option value="<?php echo $get_ID; ?>"><?php echo $get_ID; ?></option>
<?php
$q = mysql_query("select * from tblnetwork");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
if($get_ID != $row1[fldNetname])
{
echo "<option value='".$row1[fldNetname]."'>".$row1[fldNetname]."</option>";$get_netname = $row1[fldNetname];
}
}
?>
</select>
```

As you can see I empty the `action` because I have a three different pages where it will proceed....
a. booking_delete_two

b. booking_delete_three.

c. delete...
Thank you in advance,!

Comment: It is a *submit* button. You will need to prevent the form from submitting when you want stay on the page…

Comment: is delete.php in same folder ? else give complete path

Comment: use ajax to delete the record

Comment: @Deepanshu,,..yes its just in the same folder

Comment: Please use camelCase variable names. http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes to your script:

```
function myFunction(evt)
{
evt.preventDefault(); // this will keep the page from submitting and aloow the rest of the script to run
var Xcancel;
var Rokay=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
if (Rokay==true)
  {
    window.location = 'delete.php'; 

  }
else
  {
  Xcancel="You pressed Cancel!";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form is being submitted to its default action. You need to prevent this submission. Just append `onsubmit = "return false"` to your form. This will prevent the form from submission.

```
<form name='form' method='post' action="" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: @Console... I empty the action because I have a two dropdown list where it is clickable where it will redirect to a different page...sorry didn't include that....

Comment: can you show the code for the dropdown list? and exactly what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Is the delete link in the dropdown? Because everything is working for me for your current case. Just change `this.form.action` to `document.form.action` and `this.form.submit` to `document.form.submit` and try again. Let me know the further details.

Comment: If the delete link is a button the above solution is working good for me. Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would be correcting how forms are meant to be validated instead of making work arounds.You best bet is to follow the same practice as what W3schools sets out below:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

So it should look like:

```
<form name="form" action="" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
    <button type="submit" name="deletePlaylist[]" value="' . $row['id'].'" style="border: 0; background: transparent; cursor: pointer;">
        <img src="image/delete.png" />
     </button>
</form>
```

EDIT:

myFunction() could then look like below:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var Xcancel;
    var Rokay=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if(Rokay == false){
        Xcancel="You pressed Cancel!";
    }

    return Rokay;
}
```

EDIT2: Added to 'myFunction()' a dynamic way of assigning the form action :p You can leave the original action attribute blank or have it as a default.

EDIT3: Seeing your drop down code I returned my answer to something like it was originally. Test it out.

Comment: @user1567453... I empty the action because I have a two dropdown list where it is clickable where it will redirect to a different page...sorry didn't include that

Comment: @PrincessToledo changed the answer to dynamically set the action value in the form.

Comment: Ok just added extra functionality to handle multiple submit buttons (kind of a case statement). The 'onClick' of the button object sets a global variable which your function can use in if-statements to decide what the action should be.

Comment: do you mean that I will put all location in one function?

Comment: @PrincessToledo Ok I just saw the dropdown code you posted. I can see you are setting the action.value for the form there. If that is the case then my original answer will work for you except you can leave the action on the form blank still. I will edit the code again

Comment: @PrincessToledo Sorry, there were two typos. Try again.

Comment: *three typo...also I hope it's not breaking because of similar typos for your code...this one is missing a semicolon --> <select name="id" onChange="this.form.action='booking_delete_three.php'this.form.submit()">

Comment: @user1567453...sorry probably i remove it when o tried to copy..there is a semicolon in code